# Clicking on reputation bar graph to bring you to reputation summary

Tags: feature-request

Just a feature request - Sometimes I'll be going through my profile and looking at my reputation gains over the past months or so - I can hover over a green bar and see how much reputation I received on which day,:

[image: RepBar1]

But if I want to see what questions/answers I participated in that day I have to go to my reputation tab and navigate down to the date:

[image: RepBar2]

I think it would be nice if clicking on the green bar on my reputation tab would bring me to that date summary! :)

Comment: I second this. Clicking the line graph in the highlights box just refreshes the page (which seems like a bug). I would've expected it to show the reputation history for that date (or a significant range including that date).

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure it wouldn't be a useful feature.

That tiny graph is just a brief overview, made without an aim to show you detailed statistics.

You can't even know what day it was exactly until you actually hover. You can't even know for sure how many it rep it is until you hover. You don't use it for browsing your rep history, or at least shouldn't, since there's a more advanced tool :)

For this purpose there's a full-featured daily reputation graph, which is two clicks away - and it actually supports click-a-day-show-me-reps feature.

> [image: Rep graph screenshot]